# Play! 2.1 / Why isn't my Jerkson dependency resolved?

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.1, jerkson

Attempting to use the forked Jerkson library from https://github.com/randhindi/jerkson. Cloned a source dependency into the folder `module` and defined the following:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "coolapp"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  lazy val jerkson = Project(
    id = "jerkson",
    base = file("module"),
    settings = Seq(
      name               := "jerkson",
      organization       := "com.codahale",
      version            := "0.6.0-SNAPSHOT",
      scalaVersion       := "2.10.0"
    )
  )

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "com.codahale" % "jerkson" % "0.6.0-SNAPSHOT",
    "jp.t2v" %% "play2.auth"      % "0.9",
    "jp.t2v" %% "play2.auth.test" % "0.9" % "test",
    "org.ocpsoft.prettytime" % "prettytime" % "1.0.8.Final",
    "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.1-1-RC2",
    "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.10.0"
  )

// resolvers follow
}
```

However, when I go to compile it gives me the following error:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.codahale#jerkson;0.6.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

Any guesses here? Strangely this is the first time I've ever needed to resolve a source dependency so spare the ignorance. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've added this repository to your `resolvers` sequence in your `Build.scala`:

```
resolvers ++= Seq("Codahale" at "http://repo.codahale.com")
```

**----------UPDATE:**

The repo.codahale.com contains only Jerkson jars for scala 2.9.x

Try this repo instead in order to grab a jar compatible with scala 2.10.x (which Play 2.1 uses):

https://github.com/cphylabs/jerkson

This [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudphysics/jerkson_2.10/0.6.3) suggests to merely add:

```
"com.cloudphysics" % "jerkson_2.10" % "0.6.3"
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't able to find a published JAR of 2.10 Jerkson on Maven. Thanks for that.

Comment: Sorry but need to de-accept temporarily. I'm getting a `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` when using the `parse` method. Looking quickly for an alternative as it seems the Java annotations are throwing the error.

Comment: Yea this is weird, I'm running java `1.6.0_45` and it's throwing that error. I wonder if CloudPhysics runs `1.7`? Or was Scala 2.10 meant for 1.7?

Comment: @DeLongey Scala 2.10 is compatible also with 1.6. If I were you, I'd try with 1.7.

Comment: Already in the process ;) Though that is an unfortunate limitation with the new version of Jerkson

Comment: Meant that I was downloading 1.7 to my Mac. New computer didn't have it installed. But yes it works now :)

Comment: Cool :) Thus it's a limitation, indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

This library should be available at `"http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"`, so no need mention other resolvers; following build script just adding `"com.cloudphysics" % "jerkson_2.10" % "0.6.3"` should work.

```
    1 import play.Project._                                                                                                                           
    2                                                                                                     
    3 name := "smartad-backend"                                                                           
    4                                                                                                     
    5 version := "1.0"                                                                                    
    6                                                                                                     
    7 playScalaSettings                                                                                   
    8                                                                                                     
    9                                                                    
   10 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(                                                                        
   11                             jdbc,                                                                   
   12                             anorm,                                                                  
   13                             "com.google.zxing"   % "core"                 % "2.0",                  
   14                             "mysql"              % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",               
   15                             "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick"               % "2.1.0",                
~  16                             "org.slf4j"          % "slf4j-nop"            % "1.6.4",                
+  17                             "com.cloudphysics" % "jerkson_2.10" % "0.6.3"                           
   18                                     
   19                            )
```

Above build script is for play framework 2.2.0.